# Sending Array from server to client NodeJs

Tags: node.js, http

I am very lost on how I can send data from server to client. I need the client javascript to access the array in the server, but I have no idea how I can do that.

**index.js**

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')
let avails = [0, 0, 0];
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
const app = express();

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
let route = req.url.replace('/', '')

let request_url = route === '' || route === '/' ? 'website.html' : route

var room = url.parse(req.url, true).query['r'];
var status = url.parse(req.url, true).query['f'];

avails[room] = parseInt(status);
console.log(avails);

console.log(request_url)

fs.exists(request_url, (exist) => {
    if (Boolean(exist) === false) {
        res.writeHead(404, {'content-type': 'text/html'})
        res.end('Page Not Found')
        return null
    }

    fs.readFile(request_url, function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200)
        res.write(data)
        res.end()
    })
   })
}).listen(8080);

app.post('/data', async (request, response) => {
    const json = JSON.stringify(avails);
    response.json(json);
});
```

**web.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Room Availability Detection System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="website.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="island">
        <div class="title">
            <p >Piano Room Availability</p>
        </div>
        <table id="avail">
            <tr id="rooms">
                <td>Room 1</td>
                <td>Room 2</td>
                <td>Room 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="status">
                <td id="1">Available</td>
                <td id="2">Available</td>
                <td id="3">Available</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="./website.js"></script>
</body>
```

If someone can guide me how I can do this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Backend

First off, I *strongly* advise you to read the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/fr/) or some tutorials. I refactored your code. Change the import methods the way you want, I believe you use `require`.

```js
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
const app = express();

// The backend shouldn't be running 24/7. You should store this data in
// a database (SQL/MongoDB/anything else), or at least in a JSON file.
const avails = Array(3).fill(0);

// Parse JSON bodies for POST requests
app.use(express.json());

// Logger. I advise you to check out "morgan" on npm,
// it's the best-known logger for express:
// app.use(morgan("dev"))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.path);
    next();
});

// You should move "website.html" to "public/website.html"
// Every file in "public/" will be staticly accessible.
// If I understood correctly, there's other files you want to serve.
// Put them there too.
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// Use get, not post! You're not creating data, but fetching data
app.get("/avails", (req, res) => res.json(avails));

// This route is to update the status of a room. Security-wise,
// it isn't very good as the array can be completely destroyed by a 
// remote client, but it works. Example: 
// POST /rooms/2/status { value: 2 }
app.post("/rooms/:room/status", (req, res) => {
    if (typeof req.body["value"] !== "number")
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "No valid new value is specified" });
    const room = +req.params["room"];
    const newStatus = req.body["value"];
    avails[room] = newStatus;
    console.log("new avails:", avails);
    res.json({ message: "Success!", avails });
});

// Connect to port 3000
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server is ready"));
```

#### Deprecation warnings

Now, a quick note on the things you're using while you shouldn't. I'm adding this because the above code doesn't replace the methods, but avoids them.

1. Use express properly please, but I think you got it by now:

   - Use the `express.static()` middleware whenever you can for static files
   - Use middlewares.
   - Use properly the `req` and `res` objects. Simplicity is your friend.
2. `url.parse` is deprecated, you should use [`new URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL), and get the search params from its `searchParams` property.
3. `fs.exists` is also deprecated.

### Frontend

You can make requests to your backend using the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API.

```js
const root = "http://localhost:3000"; // Or whatever your backend URL is

async function getAvails() {
    const url = new URL("/avails", root).href;
    const body = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
    return body.data;
}

async function setRoomState(room, value) {
    const url = new URL(`/rooms/${room}/status`, root).href;
    const body = await fetch(url, { method: "POST", body: { value } }).then(res =>
        res.json()
    );
    // Returns new avails
    return body.avails;
}

// Use these functions wherever you want
```

### Side note about your project

If your project is about counting the number of people in a room, maybe you'll want to check out an old (small) project of mine, *echo*. Here's [`echo-mum`](https://github.com/a2br/echo-mum), the backend written in TypeScript, maybe it'll help.